# CI using jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline that gets triggered as soon as a commit happens to source. I have separated the get source code and compile as two stages for better readability of build metrics. I am facing an issue of commits that happen within seconds of each other where the changed code comes in even before the build for the previous commit completes.

I was wondering if there is a way of handling this without merging the two stages and without setting concurrency of each stage to 1?

Comment: What is the "issue" you are running into? What are you trying to do?

Comment: The issue is that when the compile for the first commit is going on, source for the second commit is being fetched. Due to this compile is failing. I can avoid this by merging the get and compile stages. But that would mean that the second pipeline trigger is kept on hold for the length of time that the first pipeline takes to compile the source. Just wanted to know if this can be avoided and both pipeline's compile stage can be done without affecting the other?

Comment: You can use `lock` and `milestone` to have pipelines "serialize" execution. Another option that I think is more common is using multibranch or organization folder type plugins where `checkout(scm)` gets the exact revision that triggered the execution so it will always fetch the exact commit.